# Get all post of specific category - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to get all the posts of the category 'Business' and display them in the list of article template. However, the query returns all the posts of all categories.

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
        'post_type'        => 'post',
        'category-name'    => 'Business'
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>
<?php get_header(  ); ?>
<div class="items-leading">
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post();?>
<!--Start to display the article-->
<article class="leading-0 item visible-first" id="item-8">
                <!-- Intro image -->
                <figure class="item_img img-intro img-intro__left">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(  );?>">
                            <img src="" alt="">
                        </a>
                </figure>

                <!--  title of the article -->
                <header class="item_header">
                <h5 class="item_title heading-style-5 visible-first">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(  );?>">
                <span class="item_title_part_0 item_title_part_odd item_title_part_first_half item_title_part_first"><?php the_title( );?></span> 
                </a></h5></header>

                <!-- info about the time published and author -->
                <div class="item_info">
                    <dl class="item_info_dl">
                        <dt class="article-info-term"></dt>

                                <dd>
                            <time class="item_published">
                                <?php the_date( );?>    </time>
                        </dd>
                                <dd>
                            <address class="item_createdby">
                            <?php the_modified_author();?>  
                            </address>
                        </dd>
                                <dd>
                            <div class="komento">
                                            </div>
                        </dd>
                            </dl>
                </div>
<!-- Introtext -->
<div class="item_introtext">
    <p>
    <?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(  ), 40, '...')?>
    </p>
</div>

<!-- info BOTTOM -->

<!-- More -->
<a class="btn btn-info" href="<?php the_permalink(  ); ?>">
    <span>
        Read more   
    </span>
</a>
</article>
<div class="clearfix"></div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<!-- end items-leading -->
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Perharps something's wrong with the code ? But I don't understand since this query was based on what I've found on the internet. 
I'd be appreciated if there's any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with $args, try with this:

```
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page'   => -1,
  'post_type'        => 'post',
  'category_name'    => 'Business'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no any query issue, its just simple silly mistake.

```
<?php get_header(  ); ?>
```

will be in initial of file & then place your query arg & all.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...I'm not sure but somehow I changed the query and this runs well ._. ?

So magic.

```
<?php get_header(  ); ?>
<?php
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
        'post_type'        => 'post',
        'cat'      => '8'
      );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>
```